# Can I use threads for send mensagem to a unique kafka topic? If yes, how?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Can I use threads for send message to a single topic in kafka? I developed a kafka producer in spring boot to send message to a kafka topic, I need know if is possible to create multi-threads for send multiple message to a single topic.
For example: Create three threads in a single producer for send in the same time three different message from each threads to a single kafka topic. It's possible? There are some specific configuration for make this?

Comment: Is your question whether you can write to a single producer from several threads or how to create those threads? Either way, there's not enough info on your question to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally yes you can. KafkaProducer is thread safe.

From documentation:

> The producer is thread safe and sharing a single producer instance across threads will generally be faster than having multiple instances.

More can be found here:
https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. No specific config needed for this. A small example below :

```
    KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);


    Callable<String> sender1 = () -> {
        ProducerRecord<String, String> pr1 = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("first_topic",
                "Hello World from sender1 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        kafkaProducer.send(pr1);
        return "sent from p1";
    };

    Callable<String> sender2 = () -> {
        ProducerRecord<String, String> pr2 = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("first_topic",
                "Hello World from sender2 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        kafkaProducer.send(pr2);
        return "sent from p2";
    };

    Callable<String> sender3 = () -> {
        ProducerRecord<String, String> pr2 = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("first_topic",
                "Hello World from sender3 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        kafkaProducer.send(pr2);
        return "sent from p3";
    };

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    CompletionService<String> compService = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(executorService);

    compService.submit(sender3);
    compService.submit(sender2);
    compService.submit(sender1);
```

And if you check the messages in the console consumer, something as below would appear:

```
Hello World from sender1 pool-1-thread-2
Hello World from sender3 pool-1-thread-1
Hello World from sender2 pool-1-thread-2
```